# Hide Network computer from network monitors

Tags: ip

I want to be as paranoid as possible. Think as madness can be! How it is possible to hide entire your linux box? Assume you have a network password to access some cafe for example. If i do run a virtual machine with nat or bridge, their network monitor can link the vm ip with host-my actual linux box?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: So you want to use the network without the network knowing that you exist?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to accomplish and what virtual machines have to do with it. Do you want to have two systems (one a VM) look like one? Please edit your question adding more detail and explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to be paranoid to know that running a virtual machine is not "hiding" anything. You just have to understand how networking works.

When you connect to a local area network via Wi-Fi or ethernet, for example, it is trivial for the network owner to know that your box is there. You can't simultaneously use the connection  AND be "invisible". Adding a virtual machine does absolutely nothing to change that. If nothing else, you'll be detected at the physical layer, or the link layer, even if your box emits no packets and ignores all inbound packets.

Even if you had a wide open ethernet hub that you wanted to sniff packets on by just passively listening to the traffic, the hub would become "aware" of your connection as soon as you establish the physical and link layer connections. You can't simultaneously connect and not be detected.

Also, I usually assume good faith, but the short and pointed nature of this question sounds like you are trying to do something illegal like steal someone else's Wi-Fi. I see no reason to help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually that hard; squelching all ARP packets and ignoring all ARP requests is usually enough to do it. Of course, the flip side is that you can't actually use any network resources via TCP/IP since no one will know how to route packets destined for your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Disable all network interfaces. Don't use that vhost for anything internet related.